How can I Flip Face with Proximity Node?
Need a little help setting up my geometry nodes. I want to animate a color change (different colors on front and back side of a face) for a low poly mesh (now an icosphere) from left to right. How can I control Flip Face with a proximity node?



For flipping individual faces, the Split Edges node is not necessary - flipping does not rotate the face itself so that vertices change places, it only rotates the normal orientation. If you needed it for any other reason, feel free to put it back in.
Now for the solution, just check with a Compare node if the Distance is below a certain threshold value and if so, use the result as Selection for the Flip Faces node.


That was exactly what I wanted, thank you so much for explaining.
